# Check if layer exist in current packet in pyshark-Python

Tags: python, layer, pcap

I'm using pyshark to read a pcap file and I want to print some fields of each layer contained in each packet.

I'm putting an if condition to check if an specific layer is present in the current packet and if True, print some field.

The condition works well when the layer exist in pkt.layers, but I'm getting "raise AttributeError()" when the layer
doesn't exist, in my case tcp layer doesn't exist in the first packet then I get error and script stops.

The content of pkt.layers has this format

```
[<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <TCP Layer>]
```

and it seems to be a list but if I try to evaluate as below if any of those string exist the result is always False.

```
>>> layers = pkt.layers
>>> layers
[<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <TCP Layer>]
>>> "<ETH Layer>" in layers
False
```

How would be the correct way to check if some layer exist?

My current code is:

```
import pyshark

# Open saved trace file
cap = pyshark.FileCapture('file.pcap')

for pkt in cap:
    lyr = pkt.layers # Current layers

    if p.eth in lyrs: print p.eth.src  # If Ethernet layer exists print ethernet value
    if p.ip in lyrs: print p.ip.src    # If IP layer exists print source IP
    if p.tcp in lyrs: print p.tcp.port  # If TCP layer exists print port
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if("protocol" in str(p.layers):
    doSomething()
```

Example:

```
if("TCP" in str(p.layers)):
    print "tcp found"
```

Works for me!

Comment: Thank you Azo for answer and help!